Office365 error for bad SPF config but i already added
I am setting up a mail server but encountering issues with emails sent from Outlook. When I send an email from a Gmail account to my custom address (e.g., user@yolo.com), it works without any errors. However, sending an email from an Outlook account results in the following error:

This error occurs when SPF (Sender Policy Framework) validation of the recipient's domain failed. If you are the recipient's mail administrator, check with your domain registrar to ensure that the SPF records associated with your domain are correctly configured. Office 365 supports only one SPF record (i.e., a TXT record that defines SPF) for your domain. Include the following domain name: spf.protection.outlook.com. If you have a hybrid configuration (i.e., if some of your mailboxes are in the cloud and others locally) or if you're a standalone Exchange Online Protection customer, add the outgoing IP address of your local servers to the TXT record.

To resolve this, I updated my SPF record as follows (assuming 123.123.123.124 is my public IP address):
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com a mx ip4:123.123.123.124 -all

Despite this change, I am still receiving the same error. Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue?

DNS updates can take up to 48 hours before it is available everywhere. Test your spfrecord from https://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx to make sure, then test outlook again

Thanks for you comment. I have tested my domain with the website you gave me and it returns me the correct SPF record. But when i test with outlook. Nothing seems to change

DNS needs 48 hours to propagate everywhere on the planet. Give it 48 hours from the moment you made the change, and test it again afterwards.

Is any difference after 48 hours?

Nothing since. I still have the same problem. The domain name is cri-maroc.com
